# Wetlands Symbol for QGIS point pattern fill

Tags: qgis, symbology

Is there a marker available anywhere for point pattern fill that resembles the standard wetlands symbol used in USGS topographic and other maps? Any good standard symbol that will be intuitively recognized as wetlands?

Comment: You want to symbolize a polygon layer, right (point pattern fill)?

Comment: Yes, Artwork.  That's right.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the OSGeo map symbol set list:

http://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/OSGeo_map_symbol_set

they list a bunch of resources where you can find symbols that are free to use. There is also a link to the USGS topo symbols. If you come on a day when there is no government shut down you might find what you are looking for there or browse the other lists from OSGeo.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I think I'll see what USGS has when they reopen.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

1. Install free photo editor app such as [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/)
2. [Install SVG plugin](http://registry.gimp.org/node/100)
3. Find a free image web site showing a wetland symbol and take a screen capture of it
4. Open GIMP paste in screen capture crop image and export to SVG
5. In QGIS go to your wetland layer properties>Style>Change, select SVG fill for Symbol layer type and browse for your saved wetland SVG

Comment: Or you could find an existing SVG symbol (e.g. http://www.sjjb.co.uk/mapicons/contactsheet) and use it. If you need to edit it, you could try Inkscape or the SVG Plugin for GIMP at artwork21 suggested.